# Google Maps SDK for iOS returns blurry map

Tags: ios, google-maps

I have attached a blurry image of google map.
I am using the iOS SDK for google. 
Please could someone suggest why this is happening ? 
On some locations, it works fine, but when I go to some other locations, the google map image is blurry.

[image: Blurry image]

Comment: Looks like a connectivity issue, where the higher-resolution map tiles couldn't be downloaded (yet).

Comment: Its not a connectivity issue. I have tried it on both wifi and LTE

Answer (score 0):

If you found bad data in Google Maps you should follow the procedure described in Google Maps help center and report the issue to Google.

> #### Report an image problem
>
> If you’ve found an image you would like further blurred, or an image you believe contains objectionable content, follow these steps:
>
> - Locate the image.
> - Click or tap Report a problem.
>
>   - On desktop, Report a problem is located in the bottom-right of the image window.
>   - On mobile, Report a problem is located from the flag or menu buttons.
> - Select the issue and submit. **We’ll review your report promptly.**

source: https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094088

I hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, but this is more a API problem.

Comment: In theory Google Maps app and Google Maps SDK should use the same tile imagery. Do you mean that imagery is OK in Google Maps app, but is blurry in the SDK?

Comment: I would suggest reaching out to Google via their [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188833&template=789005) and report this issue.